# Pass user info to SSR html email

Tags: meteor

I've created an email that sends when a button is clicked however I'm not sure how I take the users name and get it into the email. There is variable data `emailData` however that is on the server side. How do I get the users first name into the email?

Path: `database schema`

```
"profile": {
    "firstName": "SomeGuy",
    }
```

Path: `server/email.js`

```
// In your server code: define a method that the client can call
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'html-email.html' ) );

    var emailData = {
      name: "Doug Funny",
    };

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });
  }
});
```

Path: `private/html-email.html`

```
Hi {{name}},

This is a test email
```

Path: client/emailButton.js

```
Template.emailButton.events({
  'click .send-email-button': function () {

    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'test@email.com',
            'test@email.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!',
            'This is just some text. If removed this email send stops working');    
    }


 });
```

**UPDATE**

Path: client/emailButton.js

```
'submit #myForm': function () {

    var otheruserId = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'test@email.com',
            'Hello from Meteor!',
            otheruserId);    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the username of user who made the request then you can use `Meteor.user()` or `Meteor.userId()` like this,

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'html-email.html' ) );

   var user = Meteor.user();
   // OR
   // var userId = Meteor.userId();
   // var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId });

    var emailData = {
      name: (user && user.profile && user.profile.firstName) || ""
    };

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });
  }
});
```

**UPDATE: If it is for different user**

Since you have the other user's id on the client side, you need send that as a parameter to the Meteor.method. See the method below with additional parameter `userId`

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text, userId) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'html-email.html' ) );

    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId });

    var emailData = {
      name: (user && user.profile && user.profile.firstName) || ""
    };

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });
  }
});
```

Now on the client side, you can do,

```
Meteor.call("sendEmail", to, from , subject, text, otheruserId);
```

Comment: That works. What if the user is looking at another user account. How do I get the name of that user.

Comment: @bp123 If you need another user's name, you need to have a unique field like `id`, `username` or `email` of that user, so that you can do `var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: id });` (or similar query for `username` or `email`) instead of `var user = Meteor.user()`.

Comment: Yeh on the client side I do using `self.autorun(function() {
  var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
  self.subscribe('candidateProfile', id);
 });` how do I use that on the server side?

Comment: @bp123 updated answer. please let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: OK. so a follow on to this is how do you change it from a click event to a submit event. On submitting a form, if the form submits correctly then the email is sent.

Comment: @bp123 you need to use submit event instead of click event and provide form id or class instead of button class. 'click .send-email-button' should be changed to 'submit .form-class' or 'submit #form-id'.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the updated code. When i change it to submit it stops working.

Comment: @bp123 did you change button type to submit? <input type="submit" value="Send Mail" />

Comment: Yes, it's an autoform `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary makeOffer">Make Offer</button>`

Comment: @bp123 Oh, does your `emailButton` template has form or `emailButton` template is embedded inside another template that has form? If your form and button are in the same template, it should work. If your form and button are in two separate templates then I don't know how to achieve that. May be you can ask a separate question so that more people will look at it and more possible answers. :)